# Do Kepler's laws (really) solve the Kepler problem? And should the terms of the central force problem be treated as dependent variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics, celestial-mechanics

See the bottom for an added definition and discussion.

### Context

Note: I've never had a course in differential equations, so my question may demonstrate gross ignorance.

When the distinction is clear, I like to denote dependent quantities differently than independent quantities.  For example, $\mathfrak{r}$ represents the instantaneous value of a radial position vector; whereas $\vec{\mathit{r}}\left[t\right]$ is the analogous radial position vector function of time.

This is as much an art as a science, as in following listing of various quantities describing the "instantaneous" motion of a point-mass whose position $\mathfrak{r}$ is given as a function $\vec{\mathit{r}}\left[t\right]$ of time. There was no conscious intent to decouple velocity $\vec{\mathit{v}}\left[t\right]$ from position.  It just seemed cleaner to write velocity as a function of time, rather than as a time derivative.  But those are the only quantities which I am treating as functions, and only in so much as they are evaluated once during the exercise.

[image]

### The Central Force Problem (CFP)

A typical statement of the *central force problem* is: find the solutions to the vector differential equation

\begin{align}
m\ddot{\mathfrak{r}}=-mf\left(\mathfrak{r}\right)\frac{\mathfrak{r}}{r},
\end{align}

where $f$ is a known function of position. Mass $m$ is a constant.

So, clearly $f$ is a function (dependent variable).  Since we have a second derivative of position with respect to time, it seems reasonable to treat position as a function of time.  Since acceleration is given as a function of position, it might be reasonable to consider $f$ and $\ddot{\mathbf{r}}=\ddot{\vec{\mathit{r}}}\left(\mathfrak{r}\right)$ as functions of $\mathfrak{r}=\vec{\mathit{r}}\left(t\right).$  It may be a bit nebulous to ask, but; **is this a good way to think about the generic CFP?  That is, should the different terms be treated as dependent variables with the suggested order of dependency?**

### The Kepler Problem

Hopefully, the second part of my question is more tangible.  There are multiple ways to arrive at Kepler's three laws if we replace $f$ with Newton's inverse square law.  At least in the case where $\left\Vert\mathfrak{r}\right\Vert$ is either a maximum or a minimum, given an initial velocity and initial position, the shape and period of the obit is determined.  We also have that the areal velocity (or equivalently, the angular momentum) is a constant with respect to time.  What we don't have, in general, is a closed form expression for position as a function of time.  The the cases of exponential growth and the harmonic oscillator, the solutions are explicit functions of time.

So I ask: **are Kepler's laws a solution to the Kepler problem in the sense of being solutions to the differential equation**

\begin{align}
m\ddot{\mathfrak{r}}=-G\frac{mM\mathfrak{r}}{r^3}?
\end{align}

---

Edit to add:

#### Solution Defined

This is from [The Geometry of Celestial Mechanics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/geometry-of-celestial-mechanics/F285E8C089E2A1880864C8708C6BE81D), by Hansjörg Geiges.

> By a solution of the (CFP) we mean a $\mathscr{C}^2$-map $\mathbf{r}:I\to\mathbb{R}^3\backslash\left\{\mathbf{0}\right\}$
> defined on some interval $I\to\mathbb{R},$ that satisfies the differential equation (CFP).

I guess if I keep reading, I may find an answer to my question.  At first sight, it looks to be a clear affirmation that Kepler's laws provide a solution to the Kepler problem.  But what does this definition really mean? The mapping $\mathbf{r}$ implies a parameter.  Should $\ddot{\mathbf{r}}$ mean a derivative with respect to that parameter?  If so, then Kepler's ellipse isn't sufficient.  If it merely means a parameterized set of points at which (CFP) is satisfied, and leaves such details as the meaning of $\ddot{\mathbf{r}}$ to context, then we apparently do have a solution.

My inclination is to say: *No, the ellipse is not a complete solution.*  But I am not an authority on the topic.

Comment: Isn't it [Kepler's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion), and not Keppler's?

Comment: Have you opened a generic classical mechanics textbook treating the question? If you did, why is the solution not satisfactory?

Comment: I can post several derivations of Kepler's laws.  My question is whether Kepler's laws are really solutions to the differential equation called the Kepler problem.  Did you read my question?  Kepler's laws do not give a closed form expression for position as a function of time.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Does this qualify? https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781316410486  See my updated question.

Comment: The solution of Kepler's problem is the solution of the differential equation you stated. A subset of those solutions correspond to ellipses satisfying Kepler's laws (not quite because Kepler stated for instance that the Sun is in one of the focal points, and that is actually not true). See also this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion).

Comment: @Raskolnikov What is the expression for position as a function of time that solves the second order vector differential equation known as the Kepler Problem?  Apparently Kepler's laws are statements about the nature of such a solution, but are not, themselves a solution.

Comment: To get a function of time you need to solve the Kepler equation $Mt=E+e\sin(E)$ to translate the mean anomaly $Mt$ into the eccentric anomaly $E$ and insert that into the ellipse equations $x=a\cos(E)-c$,$y=b\sin(E)$. That is all for "local coordinates". For "global coordinates" you need to apply offsets and a rotation to conform with the initial conditions. Or go further to the true anomaly to get the polar coordinates in the plane of the orbit. See for example https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/40700/solving-keplers-equation-with-newton-raphson-method